# Change form hash (token) expiration Zend Framework

Tags: session, zend-framework, hash, csrf

I am using ZF's `Zend_Form_Element_Hash` to protect my form against `CSRF`. 
The problem however is that the token generated expires too soon. I'm guessing the problem is with the session lifetime, because that is where it is stored.

I use this code to generate it:

```
$token = new Zend_Form_Element_Hash('tk');
$token->setSalt(md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), TRUE)));
```

Is there any way I can make the token valid for a longer period of time?

Am I doing it right or there is a better way? I am new to Zend Framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is also a `timeout` property within Zend_Form_Element_Hash that serves as a TTL for the CSRF token.  By default it is 300 seconds (5 minutes).

You can increase this timeout by passing a value for `timeout` as an option.

```
$token = new Zend_Form_Element_Hash('tk', array('timeout' => 900)); // 15 minute TTL
```

[Zend_Form_Element_Hash API Doc](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/db_Form_Element_Hash.html)